# How to add registry certificate to HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, client-certificates

My apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question. I am new to the 'lingo' of `HttpWebRequest` and my google searching turned up fruitless.

Some time ago I wrote a login controller that utilizes `HttpWebRequest`. It works fine when I run it at home. I tried the same login controller from behind my company's firewall and it is expecting a Client Authentication certificate to get through. I read online that the certificate lives in my desktop's system registry. Sure enough, I can open IE and internet options->content->certificates I can see in the dialog window the client certificate that IE is using to do the same thing I want to accomplish with my login controller.

***Can someone please provide a C# code snippet showing a way add the client certificates from the registry to my HttpWebRequest?***

for example,

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.someplace.com/Login");
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(); //<---- ? how to add registry certs?
                request.KeepAlive = true;
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

This MS knowledge base article covers what you need - [How to send a client certificate by using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895971).

As described in the article, you have two options open to you:

1. Use the `X509Certificate` class to read the cert from a .cer file.
2. Use CryptoAPI calls to extract the certificate information directly from the certificate store.

The second option is a nuisance, and needs elevated trust to extract from the cert. store. So you'll want to go for option 1 if possible. Something like this:

```
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                         .Create("https://YourServer/sample.asp");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Snixtor. I got this far too in my discovery process. The problem is that your example loads the cert from the file system. from what I discovered the certs lives in the registry (a db) and not on the file system. The solution then becomes something related to extracting it from the registry. I'll keep trucking' and post my answer if I find it. in the meantime if anyone knows the trick please post.

Comment: My answer *does* detail what you need. Don't just look at the code sample and move on. Read the response, and look at the MS knowledge base article. Method 2 (using CryptoAPI calls) will pull the certificate directly from the cert store (the registry). I haven't posted a full code sample of that because, well, it would just be a (large) copy-paste from the KB article. If CyrptoAPI is out of the question, then as detailed in the article *"use Microsoft Internet Explorer to export the .cer file"* and use method 1.

Comment: Note that the posted link is very outdated - it's for .Net 1.1. In more recent versions of .Net, you can read certificates from the certificate store using a .Net API - see the X509Store class. http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/adding-certificate-to-request-in-net.html